# How to annotate bunch of classes at once?

Tags: java, annotations

I have a situation with a large package of DTOs. I'm trying to implement the @JsonView annotation on all of them but going and annotating every single DTO will take a lot of time. Is there an easier way to do this? I tried applying the @JsonView annotation at package level using package-info.java file but it seems that the @JsonView annotation from Jackson doesn't support package level annotations.

Comment: You could write a template and generate it but at the end you will be faster just to do it by hand. Programming is also routine work

Comment: Simon is right. To speed it up try replacing a common element of each file you select from a search.. I.e. replace "public class" with "import...;  @jsonview public class". Should be able to replace things pretty quickly. You can mass code format to make it pretty again.